# Set multiple attributes with jquery

Tags: jquery

Somewhere I've made a mistake in the btn.attr() but can't find it. Or apparently it doesn't work like I thought it would,so now I'm confused. I could do it in javascript with "with" but I'd love to learn how to do it in jquery also. So here is the code:

```
function setattr(id, value) {
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btn.attr({
        id: id,
        class: "btnclass", 
        value: "value"
        });};
```

Could I have also used $(this) somehow?

Comment: You misses a `"` here `value: "value`..

Comment: "value" <-- you need one more double quote.

Comment: Yeah still it doesn't work. Check my comment on the correct answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the right way but

- you have a syntax problem (string `"value"` not closed)
- `btn` is a DOM element, not a jQuery one
- `class` is a reserved word

Do this :

```
$(btn).attr({
    id: id,
    "class": "btnclass", 
    value: "value"
});
```

Note that those errors should have been spotted by looking at your browser's console.

Comment: That's excellent. That's the answer I was expecting. Well class was the problem. Value I added it here in stackoverflow. It wasn't in the original code and I also tried $(btn) but obviously class the error. It's a greasemonkey script so there is no debugging unfortunately :( Thank you very much. I'll accept your answer in 4 mins :)

Comment: Actually `"class"` is not necessary. I just checked it without " "  and it works fine. :/ `$(btn)` must have been the problem. That's weird. I should have done something else wrong when I was trying it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
var btn = document.createElement('input');
...
```

You can simply:

```
var btn = $('<input type="button" id="'+id+'" class="btnclass" value="value"/>');
```

You can then assign this to your page using `.appendTo()`, `.prependTo()`, or various other methods jQuery provides.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/beYeq/).

Comment: Cleaner and readable? You can always separate the attributes into an object as Palash Mondal's answer below does if you want it to be "cleaner and readable". It's basically the same thing though.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this:

```
function setattr(id, value) {
    var $btn = $('<input/>', {
        id: id,
        class: "btnclass",
        type: 'button',
        value: value
    });
}
```

Please, don't forget to append the new `btn` to an `element`.

Answer (score 0):

try this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/PezLp/3/)**

```
function setattr(id, value) {
var btn = document.createElement('input');

 $(btn).attr({
    type: 'button',
    id: id,
    class: "btnclass", 
    value: value
});
//bind event
$(btn).on('click', function(){
  alert('work....');
});
  $('body').append(btn);
};
```

Comment: `bind()` is deprecated, you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yes, I have changed :)